# Powershell script executed on each file in a folder?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a powershell script, which print out some information regarding the files which passed in as argument..

The command for executing the script, it done as such:

```
.\myscript.ps1 -accessitem C:\folder
```

I want to apply the script on all files and folder on the drive `C:`, is it possible i for loop to list all files, and pass the path as argument for the script?

The script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
    [String]$AccessItem
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
If ($Error) {
    $Error.Clear()
}
$RepPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$RepPath = $RepPath.Trim()
$str = $AccessItem -replace ':',''
$str = $AccessItem -replace '/','.'

$FinalReport = "$RepPath\"+$str+".csv"
$ReportFile1 = "$RepPath\NTFSPermission_Report.txt"

If (!(Test-Path $AccessItem)) {
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "`t Item $AccessItem Not Found." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host
}
Else {
    If (Test-Path $FinalReport) {
        Remove-Item $FinalReport
    }
    If (Test-Path $ReportFile1) {
        Remove-Item $ReportFile1
    }
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "`t Working. Please wait ... " -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host
    ## -- Create The Report File
    $ObjFSO = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
    $ObjFile = $ObjFSO.CreateTextFile($ReportFile1, $True)
    $ObjFile.Write("NTFS Permission Set On -- $AccessItem `r`n")
    $ObjFile.Close()
    $ObjFile = $ObjFSO.CreateTextFile($FinalReport, $True)
    $ObjFile.Close()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ObjFSO) | Out-Null
    Remove-Variable ObjFile
    Remove-Variable ObjFSO
    If((Get-Item $AccessItem).PSIsContainer -EQ $True) {
        $Result = "ItemType -- Folder"
    }
    Else {
        $Result = "ItemType -- File"
    }
    $DT = Get-Date -Format F
    Add-Content $ReportFile1 -Value ("Report Created As On $DT")
    Add-Content $ReportFile1 "=================================================================="
    $Owner = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $AccessItem).GetAccessControl() | Select Owner
    $Owner = $($Owner.Owner)
    $Result = "$Result `t Owner -- $Owner"
    Add-Content $ReportFile1 "$Result `n"
    (Get-Item -LiteralPath $AccessItem).GetAccessControl() | Select * -Expand Access | Select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights, AccessControlType, IsInherited, InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags | Export-CSV -Path "$RepPath\NTFSPermission_Report2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    Add-Content $FinalReport -Value (Get-Content $ReportFile1)
    Add-Content $FinalReport -Value (Get-Content "$RepPath\NTFSPermission_Report2.csv")
    Remove-Item $ReportFile1
    Remove-Item "$RepPath\NTFSPermission_Report2.csv"
    Invoke-Item $FinalReport
}
If ($Error) {
    $Error.Clear()
}
```

I would prefer a outside command doing this, as workings of the script should not be altered, it it used for single file testing..

Comment: Show us your code that is working on the files and we can help you with that code.

Comment: Normally this would be done with `-Recurse`. We will need to know what   `myscript.ps1` includes in order give you an accurate solution.

Comment: @jrider I have added the script.

Comment: I commend to your attention the cmdlets [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6), as well as [`about_pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6), all of which can be assembled to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Add `-Recurse` Flag to the script
2. Run the script on each directory

I'm going with option two since the script looks complicated enough that I don't want to touch it.

```
$path_to_script = "C:\path\to\myscript.ps1"
$start_directory  = "C:\folder"

# Call Script on Parent Directory
& "$path_to_script" -AccessItem "$start_directory"

# Call Script on any Child Directories within the "$start_directory"
foreach($child in (ls "$start_directory" -Recurse  -Directory))
{
    $path = $child.FullName
    & "$path_to_script" -AccessItem "$path"
}
```

Basically, I'm calling the script on the parent directory and any sub-directories within the parent directory.

Comment: Why not `Get-ChildItem -Path «root-of-search» -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object { «fq-path-to-script» $_ }`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes, that would work too. I prefer `foreach` over `Foreach-Object`, but that's a personal preference

Comment: `foreach` and `Foreach-Object` are one and the same thing. For details `Get-Alias ForEach`

Comment: Then you could do `ForEach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem ...)) { «script» $folder }`, no?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh That is a very common misconception. foreach is a statement, like if, for, or while. ForEach-Object is a command, like Get-ChildItem. There is also a default alias of foreach for ForEach-Object, but it is only used when there is a pipeline. See the long explanation in Get-Help about_Foreach, or click the link in my previous comment which goes to an entire article by Microsoft's The Scripting Guys about the differences between the statement and the command.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh - No, they are not. There is a scripting loop construct `ForEach` that is _not_ the same as `ForEach-Object`; they are the same only when using `ForEach` in the pipeline.

Comment: @KolobCanyon thanks for the script, but it only includes directories, and want both direcotories and files.

Comment: Yes I got that. Thanks for the info guys.

Comment: @Lamda Just remove `-Directory` if you want directories and files. I was under the impression that `$AccessItem` required a directory? Because in your example you only specify a directory as a parameter?

Comment: Perfect... and exactly as I imagined it.